# Dynamic eloquent query injecting is not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm trying to build dynamic query using form inputs like below :

```
 $query = new Doctor();

 if (!empty($request->input('city'))) {
    $city = $request->input('city');
    //Search for any thing like doctor name or last name
    $query->where('city_id', $city);
 }


  //Get doctor names result in collection type
  $col = $query->where('level','LIKE','%%')->orderBy($Order_By, $Sort_Type)->toSql();
```

Problem is the part which check city and inject city where clause into query is not working and what I get as a query is :

```
"select * from `doctors` where `level` LIKE ? order by `profile_views` desc"
```

if I change the logic and put city where clause in single line like :

```
 $col = $query->where('city_id', $city)->where('level','LIKE','%%')->orderBy($Order_By, $Sort_Type)->toSql();
```

The result of this query is :

```
"select * from `doctors` where `city_id` is null and `level` LIKE ? order by `profile_views` desc"
```

how can I make the first logic to work ?

Comment: I'd guess that `$city` is probably null. Have you checked it with `var_dump($city)`?

Comment: To extend @aynber's statement, you probably want `$query = Doctor::query();` - although I suspect Bill is *also* correct.

Comment: @BillKarwin it's not related to the value of $city because i've set a string value to it and still it didn't show up in query.

Comment: @ceejayoz Doctor::query() solved the issue :))  but another problem i'm facing is ErrorException in helpers.php line 519:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini I suggest you ask a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini You're likely dumping something in the Blade templates with `{{ $variable }}` that isn't a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = new Doctor();
```

creates a new Doctor, but you don't really want that. Instead:

```
$query = Doctor::query();
```

creates a new *query* against the Doctor model, which can then be extended with `where()` etc. stuff.